# How to write a subquery in where condition in Azure cosmos db to get a id which has different source id's in multiple documents but in same collection

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I've one collection which has multiple documents as below. How write select query to orderid's which has two source's  "OrderStatus", "PlacedOrder"  in Azure Cosmos?

I am trying below queries but they are not working

1. select c.orderid from c where  c.source='OrderStatus' and c.source='PlacedOrder'
2. select c.orderid from c where c.source='OrderStatus' and c.orderid in (select c.orderid from c where c.source='PlacedOrder')

Please help me writing this query in right way. Thanks!.

[
{
"source": "PlacedOrder",
"orderid": "10490102",
"storeid": "50",
"data": {}
}
]

[
{
"source": "OrderStatus",
"orderid": "10490103",
"storeid": "50",
"data": {}
}
]

[
{
"source": "OrderStatus",
"orderid": "10490102",
"storeid": "50",
"data": {}
}
]

Comment: Please be mindful of tags. For example, you tagged this as `cosmos` and that tag says explicitly that it has nothing to do with Cosmos DB. I removed that, and other unrelated tags, accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In both your queries, you're executing an `AND` on the value of `c.source`. This is why you're not getting any results (it can't be two values at once).

Try `ARRAY_CONTAINS()`, with a list of possible source values:

```
SELECT c.orderid
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS (["OrderStatus","PlacedOrder"],c.source)
```