# Azure CosmosDB User Defined Function returns records equal to the total number of records in the table

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am just no understanding how user defined functions in CosmosDB works.

Why is the my UDF in Cosmos DB returning results equal to the number of records in the table?

My table has 4 records currently.

Here are the records -

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "14168000000",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 1"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "18055678978",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 2"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "17202228799",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 3"
        },
        {
            "partitionKey": "user",
            "userPhoneNumber": "17780265987",
            "userDisplayName": "Test User 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my UDF -

```
function findUserByPhoneNumber(users, contactNumbers){
    var result;
    for (let i = 0; i < contactNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (contactNumbers[i] == "14168000000") {
            result = contactNumbers[i];
        }
    return result;
}
```

Here is my SQL -

```
SELECT udf.findUserByPhoneNumber(c,["14168000000","17200000000"]) FROM c
```

And here is the result I am getting -

```
[
    {
        "$1": "14168000000"
    },
    {
        "$1": "14168000000"
    },
    {
        "$1": "14168000000"
    },
    {
        "$1": "14168000000"
    }
]
```

I am only expecting one record to be returned.

Comment: You're comparing specific elements of your `contactNumbers` array to `"14168000000"`, once per document. Every single time, you match element 0 and return that value. You're never comparing anything to content in your documents, and you're not returning any data in your documents - you're just returning a value from your array. If you had 100 documents, you'd return that value 100 times.

Comment: @DavidMakogon could you throw in an example. I just want an array to be returned when the match happens. I am also wondering if UDF is not the way to go for this specific scenario.

Comment: There's no need for a UDF, for what you're doing. You can use `ARRAY_CONTAINS` to accomplish the same thing. You can look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194997/272109) that shows this, as well as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537663/272109) too.

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` statement in your query will never help you filter items in your query. If you want to filter you should use `WHERE` in your query. While you could use a UDF in a `WHERE` statement that returns e.g. a boolean you should typically avoid it as the database can not use it indexes to efficiently retrieve your data and will have to use your UDF on every document to calculate if it should be retrieved.

For your scenario the query could be:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM c
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(['14168000000', '17200000000'], c.userPhoneNumber)
```

The reason your UDF always returns `14168000000` is because you always use the array `['14168000000', '17200000000']` as input in your UDF and check if any of those values equals `14168000000` and return that.

Comment: Thanks NotFound. The reason why I went with the UDF here is I need to do a LIKE check as the phone numbers I sent in won't be a like for like on the database. The phone numbers sometimes won't be having country codes.

Comment: If the number of possibilities is very limited (e.g. with and without country code) I would just add those possibilities into the array. If you really need a `LIKE` query you could chain multiple statements together in the `WHERE` clause, but try to avoid queries that do a full scan of the database https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/query/string-functions. The best situation would just be having a standardized way phone numbers are saved so you don't run on such data quality issues.

Comment: The data is stored in the database with the country codes, so there are no data quality issues with the data in the database. The phone numbers that I am sending in are phone numbers stored in the phone contacts app. People don't usually follow any standardized format when storing the phone numbers in their contacts book and that's why I am having this issue. The intent here is to check whether the phone numbers they have in the contacts book is already there in the cosmos db database.